# How to prioritize Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with this code written by somebody else and it is to load an image and a YouTube Video. My understanding his that I can change the priority of the script. Right now, it seems that when someone goes on this website with an iPhone and they hit the play button in front of the image, the video does not play, because the script is not finished loading. How do I alter the code below so that if the page or this script is not finished loading, the end user cannot see a play button?

By the way, this problem does not happen on an Android device, so I am not sure if that piece of information will serve as a clue.

I hope this makes sense because I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player1;
var player2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player1 = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    playerVars: {
      'controls': 0,
      'rel': 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  jQuery('.video-overlay').click(function() {
    event.target.setVolume(100);
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.video-overlay').css('transform', 'scale(0)');
      jQuery('.homepage-tagline').hide();
    }, 300);
    event.target.playVideo();
  });
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  jQuery('.video-overlay').click(function() {
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');
    jQuery('.video-overlay').hide();
    jQuery('.slider-overlay').hide();
    event.target.playVideo();
  });
}

function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

I tried adding this piece of code:

```
jQuery('.video-overlay').css('opacity', 0);
```

but it didn't do much.

Comment: Give the player 0 opacity and add code in the `onPlayerReady` function that sets it to 1. Also mentioning *platforms* is a lot less relevant than mentioning *browsers*. Does chrome on iOS have the same behavior as Android or Safari? See?

Comment: looks like you video overlay is the thing you click to play it so why not hide it in css and then do a `.show` in your video player ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to set the pointer-events to none and when onPlayerReady is fired, set the target.style.pointerEvents = "all"

Comment: So, I would set event.target.setVolume(0) in the onPlayerReady function?

Comment: Interesting, I was told this had to do with changing priority of javascript, but it seems it has to do with pointer-events which I have no experience with.

Comment: @Daniel setting the pointer-events in CSS to none will disallow any event listeners to pass through (such as clicks) so that the user cannot click on the play button until you set the firstScriptTag.style.pointerEvents = "all". Doing it this way will make it work but will not make the best user experience - it will confuse the user why it isn't playing when they click the play button the first time. It will at least fix the issue though

Comment: hey Kody, yes i was actually working on that until another fire started that I am trying to put out right now. Thank you and I will keep you posted.